# How to rewrite url-encoded-base64 with .htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, url-rewriting, base64

I have used timthumb to resize images from external site. I would like rewrite url to security my site
But I don't know how to do it with .htaccess and php

(1) htp://mydomain.com/timthumb.php?src=**htp://any-images.jpg**&h=70&w=70&zc=1

(2) htp://mydomain.com/70/70/aHR0cDovL2ltYWdlc2hhY2suY29tL2EvaW1nOTEyLzE4NTgvZ3Z

I used php encode base64 **htp://any-images.jpg** to **aHR0cDovL2ltYWdlc2hhY2suY29tL2EvaW1nOTEyLzE4NTgvZ3Z**

Now the question is: How to do rewrite from (1) to (2)?

Comment: Would it make it easier for yourself if your url's had a clue as to what was in them? e.g.: `http:/example.com/thumb/70/70/aHR0cD...` instead of: `http://example.com/70/70/aHR0cD...`? Type of url e.g. 'thumb'.  It will make the '.htaccess' rules easier and more reliable.

Comment: Ofcourse, anyway. But how to do it Ryan Vincent?

Comment: Sorry i misunderstood what you want to do, what is the full url that you want the user to see in the web browser for your image url?

Comment: On web brower user will see link (2) <img src="http:/example.com/70/70/aHR0cD...">

Answer (score 1):

If you have sysadmin privilege you could use RewriteMap to define a mapping process as per the documentation, However since you are already via a PHP script you could use a regexp of the form

```
 RewriteRule ^(\d+)/([A-Za-z0-9+/]*)$ timthumb.php?h=$1&base64=$  [QSA]
```

But you would need to modify `timthumb.php` to parse the `base64` parameter and decode it.